# Posix evtsuspend equivalent

Tags: c, linux, unix, posix, lynxos

I am migrating a LynxOS program to an ubuntu distribution and gcc 4.1.3

I am almost done but I have a problem, I am receiving SIGALRM signal which forces my program to exit. I dont know why I am receiving this signals if I am not calling to alarm(x).

I roundabouted this with a sigaction, but my program is not working properly mq_receive is failing every time this SIGALRM is received.

I wonder if it could be because of this code translation:

```
#include <events.h>
#include <timers.h>

evtset_t EvtMask;
struct timespec Time;

Time.tv_sec = 2;
Time.tv_nsec = 0;
evtsuspend (&EvtMask, &Time);
```

would now be

```
sleep(2);
```

This is the info about evtsuspend given by LynxOS:

[evtsuspend](https://imgur.com/3ee24.png)
(cant insert the image because of my lack of reputation)

Do you think they work the same? (without specifying an event mask) sleep() also waits for a SIGALRM to continue.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 3):

1) Try running strace on your program to see if you can find out more info.

It'd be nice to have more details about your program... but maybe this will help.

Maybe `mq_receive()` is timing out.  I *think* that SIGALRM is used to notify applications for timed-out system calls.

Or more likely, you're using something else that's causing SIGALRM in your code, ie: `setitimer()`.

As for your question about using sleep(2) on linux.  If you want the program to block during the sleep(2) call, then yes you should be OK with using it.  If you don't want it to block, then start an interval timer `setitimer()` and use that.  Note: setitimer() uses SIGALRM when the timer fires... see the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setitimer) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old topic, but here is an answer to the `mq_receive()` part of your question:

`mq_receive()` will unblock when a signal is received. When this happens, the return code will be set to `-1` and errno will be set to `EINTR`. You can wrap code around your call to `mq_receive()` to check for this and recall it if necessary.